# Xamarin forms: Launcher icon for ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

I am trying to set the launcher icon for xamarin forms ios project from Mac.

I do the following things but still showing the default icon.

1.Double-Click the Info.plist file in the Solution Explorer to open it for editing.

2.Scroll down to the App Icons section.

3.From the Source dropdown list, select AppIcon-1.
[image]

4.Open Assets.xcassets and select App icons from the list.

5.Select the image file for the required type(Prerendered option is not checked). Some icons are already filled with the default icon and if I change that will get the file not found error.

[image]

XSAppIconAssets path in Info.plist is:

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-1.appiconset</string>
```

Is there any additional set up for this task? I refer this blog: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=vsmac

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because that `Assets file path` doesn't match the vaule in `info.plist`,  your application cannot find it so  use the default icons.

1. Right click `info.plist` and open it with `XML(Text)Editor`, you can find

   ```
   <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
   <string>Resources/Images.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
   ```
2. Right click `Assets.xcassets` and open containing folder , select its parent folder, you can find it locates at `YourApp.iOS` not `Resources`.

   [image]

#### Solution

Change `XSAppIconAssets` from `Resources/Images.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset` to `Images.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset` , it should be able to solve the issue.

Comment: @SreejithSree It still doesn't work without Resources?

Comment: <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon-1.appiconset</string>
My info.plist XSAppIconAssets path

Comment: Question edited with some screenshots, can you go through it?

Comment: @SreejithSree You should make the 2x and 3x the same file, try to delete `AppIcon-1` and create new one .

Comment: It worked now, last time got file not found error when select 2x and 3x files, but this time it no errors and it worked,why?

Comment: @SreejithSree It's hard to say, but per my experience , when something strange happens ,you can try to restart visual studio :)..