# Xamarin forms iOS changed AppIcons but remains showing old default

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Starting from a standard Xamarin forms app template and changing the app icons in assets.xcassets, I am unable to make this take effect. The initial xamarin icon keeps showing when deployed to physical devices.

In assets.xcassets, I added all the required image sized.
I ensured that in plist info this asset was set as app icons source.
I have tried cleaning, rebuilding and deleting from the ipad and iphone I am testing with. No success.

I tried deleting the default asset and creating a new one, and make pinfo point to this, and *still* the old Xamarin icon shows up. This makes me think that there is a cache somewhere on either my windows pc, on which I am developing using vs2019, or on the mac which VS is connected to for doing the actual build, and this is not getting updated, since otherwise that old icon should not exist any longer.

I did read this answer
[Xamarin forms: Launcher icon for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994279/xamarin-forms-launcher-icon-for-ios)

Which indicates that the OP has a problem with a mismatched path to the asset, but that does not seem to be the case for me. The xcasset folder is at the root of the ios project. As this is simply the default test project it is app1/App1.ios/Fawk.xcassets and the entry in pinfo is
XSAppIconAssets
Fawk.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset

Does this make any kind of sense?

Edit: Tried vs2019, xamarin forms template. Deleted default asset in assetcatalogs under ios, created a new one, set all my custom icon images (png), updated info.plist/visual assets/appicon to my new asset and then ran it on a physical device. The default xamarin icon is what shows up. This seems to indicate it is not a cache issue, as I suspected, but... something else...

Answer (score 0):

1. You can right-click Assets.xcassets and view it in the folder, there is a json file in it, please check if the file name is correct.
2. According to the official documentation, if you are not connected to a Mac, it will only display the original image. For more information, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#limitations